# Securing Drupal: Alternative to Watchdog?

Tags: security, logging, drupal

Hi Im going though and securing a site I have that runs drupal 7 using the security review module. One of the recommendations is to not use watchdog to log events to the screen I.E the data base I guess. If I turn that off would there be another secure way to send logs to my workstation so that I can monitor traffic to the site. I.E what people view, broken links and the like?

I'm on a shared host, not a dedicated host. I did a search on some different ways to do this, but I really dont know where to start. Should I download a module to do this? Or does Drupal report all this information to the server logs? Sorry if I am not formatting this question correctly, but i'm not to clear on how to do this.

Comment: SO trolls on the run. They just love down voting questions like this. This is a relevant question. +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the recommandation is about Drupal's watchdog? Not about displaying error message on the pages. These are two different things.

That said, in Drupal, the watchdog is only an API to log system messages. Where the messages go, how they are actually logged, is a pluggable system. By default, Drupal uses a module called "Database logging" (dblog) to log message to the database. A syslog module is also provided, but not really an option if you are on a shared hosting. A quick search reveal modules to send messages to [Logentries](https://www.drupal.org/project/logentries), [Logstash (and Loggly)](https://www.drupal.org/project/logs_http), [Slack](https://www.drupal.org/project/watchdog_slack), [LogIO](https://www.drupal.org/project/logio_harvester), [email](https://www.drupal.org/project/watchdog_reporter), etc.

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for, a couple of different options, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a gigantic site with millions a hits a day then, yeah, don't use watchdog. 
But if it's just a small site, just use watchdog to log your events. And seeing its a shared host, it's not a high profile site. Using watchdog is fine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am developing a site for prototype purposes that will require good security when it goes live, so now Im really considering moving it to a manage host so I can maintain good security.